# How do i set Single sign-on configuration values in a custom policy for azure b2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy setup that allows users to login using B2C credentials or Azure AD as an external IdP. This works perfectly well. I am now trying to implement the "Tenant" setting of built-in policies so that multiple apps make the users sign in only once. So if user visits example.com/app1 and signs in then they can visit example.com/app2 without having to sign in. So I modified my SignUpOrSigninWithAAD.xml to include

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" />
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

inside the RelyingParty node next to the default user journey line. This did not work. Users are asked to sign in to both apps.

Comment: There's some [new documentation on SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sso-custom).  Have you checked that out yet?

Comment: @spottedmahn I just did and it helped me figure it out. I added 
   
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/> 

to the external ClaimsProvider node in my TrustFrameworkExtenstions.xml file

Comment: Nice!  You should add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my external Azure AD Claims provider configuration. Changed the **UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement** ReferenceID value to **SM-SocialLogin**. Azure AD is an external provider in my custom policy and as such it is treated by B2C as a social provider. That is one of the weird things with dealing with B2C. Why would Azure AD be considered a social login? Anyway the answer is as stated.

Comment: A "social" account can be consider any external account whether it is a consumer-based one (Facebook, etc.) or an enterprise-based one (Azure AD, etc.).